# C++ Error: Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I'm completely new to C++ and I created this function:

```
bool guessWord(string compWord)
{
    cout << "Guess a letter: ";
    string userLetter;
    cin >> userLetter;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < compWord.length(); x++)
    {
        string compLetter = compWord[x];
        if (compLetter == userLetter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it returns to following `error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`. Can anyone help me understand what this means?

Comment: Only if you help me understand what `line 23` means.

Comment: It means that you can't convert from a char to a const char pointer. On line 23 you pass a char to something that expects a const char pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string compLetter = compWord[x];
```

`compWord[x]` gets `char` and you are trying to assign it to `string`, that's wrong.
However, your code should be something like

```
bool guessWord(string compWord)
{
    cout << "Guess a letter: ";
    char userLetter;
    cin >> userLetter;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < compWord.length(); x++)
    {
        char compLetter = compWord[x];
        if (compLetter == userLetter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If he wants to use string class only how about this: `string compLetter = (char*)&compWord[x];`

Comment: @AbhijitKadam - No, that will give a totally different result.

Answer (score 1):

`string compLetter = compWord[x];`

should be

`char compLetter = compWord[x];`

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
string compLetter = compWord[x];
```

You're assigning a char to a string.
Changing it to

```
char compLetter = compWord[x];
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

compWord[x] gives you the x'th character in string compWord, which you are then trying to assign to a string.

You should either compare both strings directly, or iterate over them in parallel and compare character by character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to see whether a character is in the `string`. If it's not, it returns `std::string::npos`:

```
bool guessLetter(string compWord)
{
    cout << "Guess a letter: ";
    char userLetter;
    cin >> userLetter;
    return compWord.find(userLetter) != string::npos;
```

}