# c++ invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am writing a little program that searches through as string for a character and returns a pointer to the first character in the string that matches the character. Every time I run the program I get the error message "error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]". This is the code that I am have written and I can't figure out how to fix this.

```
const char *strchr(const char *haystack, const char needle) {
  bool no = true;
  int i = 0;
  while (haystack[i] != '\0' && no == true) {
    if (haystack[i] != needle) {
      no = true;
      i++;
    }
    else if (haystack[i] == needle) {
      no = false;
    }
  }
  if (no == true) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  else {
    return haystack[i];
  }
}
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: My suggestion is to copy and paste `error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]` into a search engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Error: Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char\*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969281/c-error-invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char)

Comment: "I am writing a little program that searches through as string for a character and returns a pointer to the first character in the string that matches the character" Which line of your code is intended to do this `return`? What thing is being `return`ed? Is that thing a pointer? Do you see why that causes a problem?

Comment: but isn't haystack[I] a pointer? when it is declared in the function, haystack is declared as a pointer and that's why I am confused.

Comment: What? Why would `haystack[i]` be a pointer if `haystack` is a pointer? What do you think `[i]` does? Hint: when you write `haystack[i] != '\0'`, what kind of thing is `'\0'`? When you write `haystack[i] == needle`, what kind of thing is `needle`? Notice how you *don't* get an error for those comparisons? Does it make sense to compare a pointer to a `char`? Therefore, `haystack[i]` is a `char`. That's the point of `[i]`; you are grabbing one of the *pointed-at things*. `haystack` points at a sequence of `char`, so `haystack[i]` is the `i`th `char` in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is `const char*` while you are returning `haystack[i]`(with type `char`). Change return type to `char` or return some other value(foe example `return haystack + i;`)

Comment: thank you! I changed it to return haystack + i; but when it returns that it returns the character and then the rest of the string too. for example if the string is "hello" and the character I'm searching for is 'e' it return "ello". Is there a way to make it return just the character or is this what it is supposed to return?

Comment: You are returning a `char*` pointer to a specific character, but you are treating it as a pointer  to a null-terminated string.  If you want to handle just the single character, dereference the returned pointer.  Or return a single `char` to begin with, not a `char*` pointer.

Comment: That is the usual behaviour of the [`strstr` library function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) it looks like you've been tasked with reimplementing.

Comment: @gobygonagle return haystack+i; returns pointer to your char. It you want to threat it as char, dereference it(so it would be ```*strchr("abcde", 'c')```, otherwise c++ will threat it as null terminated string)